# xunit 2.4.1 use cli dotnet test --collect:"Code Coverage" not generate coverage xml

Tags: .net, xunit, dotnet-cli

I used `dotnet test --collect:"Code Coverage"`

```
PS D:\git\MiniExcel\tests\MiniExcelTests> dotnet test --collect:"Code Coverage"
#...
Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'.
Data collection : Could not find data collector 'Code Coverage'
#...
```

then I also tried

- `dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura`
- `dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover`

system also not generate coverage.xml

my test csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net5.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.0.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reference Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk as mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/blob/master/Documentation/VSTestIntegration.md)

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
```

Comment: thanks first! but it show new question `Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'XPlat Code Coverage'.`  https://i.imgur.com/1KrmNGk.png , i'm searching docs about it now

Comment: Did you try the vstest method that’s also on that page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my Azure Devops pipeline was that the developer used the built dll's as the project argument for testing. This worked for running the unit tests, but not for the code coverage. Instead of using `**/*Tests.dll` as an argument
I now changed it to `**/*Tests.csproj` and now the code coverage works.

See my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75221714/1770778).