# dotnet test is unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'

Tags: .net, xml, unit-testing, code-coverage, mstest

A few months ago, when our projects were still in .NET 4.7.2, we used to run unit tests on our Azure DevOps Server using the `Visual Studio Test` task. We used parameter `Test files` to specify which test assemblies need to run and `Code Coverage` worked just fine there.

Since we migrated our projects to .NET 5.0, we use `dotnet test` to run unit tests and now `Code Coverage` doesn't work anymore.

**Here's an example:**

```
D:\test-2-1\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe test A.Test.dll B.Test.dll C.Test.dll --logger trx --results-directory D:\test-2-1\_temp --settings D:\test-2-1\5\s\.runsettings
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.9.4
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 22 test files matched the specified pattern.
Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'.
Data collection : Could not find data collector 'Code Coverage'
```

**Content of `.runsettings`**

```
<DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
        <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
            <Configuration>
                <CodeCoverage>
                    <ModulePaths>
                        <Include>
                            <ModulePath>{someRegexToLimitCodeCoverageToSpecificTestAssemblies}</ModulePath>
                        </Include>
                    </ModulePaths>
                </CodeCoverage>
            </Configuration>
        </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
</DataCollectionRunSettings>
```

In another smaller project, `Code Coverage` still works, but here we specify which **project files** should be tested, rather than which **compiled test assemblies**.

Is this the way to go now and if yes, is it possible to get it back to work with specifying test assemblies too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am having the same issues moving from .NET Framework to latest .NET.
Any chance you want to share how you solved then issue? Thank you!

Comment: @LoriB Unfortunately, I couldn't solve it. But now, over a year later, it doesn't bother us really, because the `Code Coverage` percentage isn't important to us anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, unfortunately, it looks like this issue is still a pain with no clear solutions.

Comment: @LoriB, By coincidence I was yesterday looking for an answer as well. Today I found the solution for roli09's problem. Hope it is the cause of your problem as well. See below.

Comment: @roli09 Hope you can mark this as your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@LoriB
The problem in my Azure Devops pipeline was that the developer used the built dll's as the project argument for testing. This worked for running the unit tests, but not for the code coverage. Instead of using `**/*Tests.dll` as an argument
I now changed it to `**/*Tests.csproj` and now the code coverage works.

In the example of the question, the line

`D:\test-2-1\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe test A.Test.dll B.Test.dll C.Test.dll --logger trx --results-directory D:\test-2-1\_temp --settings D:\test-2-1\5\s\.runsettings`

should be changed to

`D:\test-2-1\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe test A.Test.csproj B.Test.csproj C.Test.csproj --logger trx --results-directory D:\test-2-1\_temp --settings D:\test-2-1\5\s\.runsettings`

or even better

`D:\test-2-1\_tool\dotnet\dotnet.exe test **/*.Test.csproj --logger trx --results-directory D:\test-2-1\_temp --settings D:\test-2-1\5\s\.runsettings`

**EDIT:**

But to answer your question:

This is what the help of dotnet.exe says:

> Usage: dotnet test [options] <PROJECT | SOLUTION> [[--] ...]]
>
> Arguments:
> <PROJECT | SOLUTION>   The project or solution file to operate on. If a file is not specified, the command will search the current directory for one.

Although I found examples with dll's, dotnet.exe asks for a **project** or **solution** file. And not a library or any other assembly. And since I couldn't get code coverage to work with the dll's I suggest not to use assemblies as input. Only project or solution files.

Comment: Thx for your input, i'm now remembering a bit better. You are right, the issue is passing the assemblies instead of the project files (as I hinted in my original post). Although my original question was more about, **IF** that's how it's supposed to be, I'll mark your answer.

Comment: Silly me, I didn't read the question well. You already know the answer, but to be complete I'll edit my answer to include an answer for your question as well.

Comment: No problem. Thx for taking the time to edit and answer my question. That's actually pretty interesting, that the help of the `dotnet.exe` differs from the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test), where they clearly state, that projects **and assemblies** are supported: `dotnet test [<PROJECT> | <SOLUTION> | <DIRECTORY> | <DLL> | <EXE>]`

Comment: Hello, it's great that you managed to find a solution by coincidence!
Unfortunately for me that did not do the trick.
Can I please ask you to share your .runsettings file?
Also, you do not have any parameter passed like </collect:"Code Coverage;Format=Cobertura">, do you confirm that?
Right now I get both these errors in my pipeline output:
Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'.
Failed to load extensions from file 'C:\Agent\Agent-Vs2022\_work\17\s\Comet.UI.UnitTests\bin\x64\Debug\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll'.

Comment: I don't have a .runsettings file. I just copied the example from the original question. The command in our project is `"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" test C:\path\myproject.csproj --logger trx --results-directory C:\someresult --configuration release --collect "Code coverage"`. Actually I'm not even the developer of this project, I'm the build manager. So if the developer cannot get it to build anymore, they come to us. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There can be many different root causes for this problem but for me adding a nuget package `Microsoft.CodeCoverage` to the test project helped.